# If a sequence of symbol class converges pointwise, then the pseudodifferential operator converges in Schwarz space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

The Schwartz space of rapidly decreasing function (as well as their derivatives) on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Fréchet space, whose (metric complete) topology is given by the usual countable family of semi-norms $\left(p_k\right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$
$$
p_k(\phi)=\max _{|\alpha|,|\beta| \leq k}\left\|x^\alpha \partial_x^\beta \phi\right\|_{L^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)}
$$

I want to show the following: Suppose we have a sequence of symbols $a_k \in S^m\left(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n\right)$ which satisfies the uniform symbolic estimates
$$
\left|\partial_x^\beta \partial_{\xi}^\alpha a_k(x, \xi)\right| \leq A_{\alpha \beta}(1+|\xi|)^{m-|\alpha|},
$$
for all $\alpha, \beta$, all $x, \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and all $k$, with constants $A_{\alpha \beta}$ independent of $x, \xi$ and $k$. Suppose that $a \in S^m\left(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n\right)$ is such that $a_k(x, \xi)$ and all of its derivatives converge to $a(x, \xi)$ and its derivatives, respectively, pointwise as $k \rightarrow \infty$. Then $a_k(X, D) f \rightarrow a(X, D) f$ in $\mathcal{S}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ for any $f \in \mathcal{S}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$

where $$
a(X, D) f(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathrm{e}^{2 \pi \mathrm{i} x \cdot \xi} a(x, \xi) \widehat{f}(\xi) \mathrm{d} \xi
$$

Of course, we can move the derivative inside the integral and turn the multiplication of $x^{\alpha}$ into differentiation and use integration by parts. This is all fine, but one of the challenges of this problem is that we cannot interchange limits and sup.  Of course, if we fix a $x$, then we can use Lebesgue-dominated convergence, but this is only for a fixed x and we need an estimate for the sup taken over all $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$.